# Replace array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have below array of objects

```
const array = [
   { home1: "05:45", dayOfWeek: 1, away: "09:30"},
   { home1: "05:15", dayOfWeek: 2, away: "09:30"},
   { home1: "17:30", dayOfWeek: 5, away: "09:30"},
   { home1: "16:30", dayOfWeek: 7, away: "09:30"}
]
```

I have four `dayOfWeek` (1,2,5,7). Now I need to push the remaining three (3,4,6) with the dummy object (`{ home1: "05:30", dayOfWeek: 7, away: "09:30"}`)

Now the logical part is I don't know which `dayOfWeek` are present in the array. There may be only one, two, three or blank. I need to push `7` days in that array every time.

How this can be done? Please suggest me the best way

Thank you!!!

Comment: Does it need to be in order?

Comment: @CertainPerformance No order can be anything.

Comment: you can loop through current array and store daysOfWeek in an array then loop the other 7 days dummy array and check if its in the previous array then do not need to insert that days. hopes you get that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to make a `Set` of the days contained in the array so far, then iterate from 1 to 7, `push`ing a new object to the array with that day if it's not contained in the set:

```js
const array = [
   { home1: "05:45", dayOfWeek: 1, away: "09:30"},
   { home1: "05:15", dayOfWeek: 2, away: "09:30"},
   { home1: "17:30", dayOfWeek: 5, away: "09:30"},
   { home1: "16:30", dayOfWeek: 7, away: "09:30"}
];
const dummy = { home1: "05:30", away: "09:30" };
const days = new Set(array.map(({ dayOfWeek }) => dayOfWeek));
for (let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
  if (!days.has(i)) array.push({ ...dummy, dayOfWeek: i });
}
console.log(array);
```

I used a `Set` to reduce complexity, but I suppose if you only ever need 7 objects, it doesn't matter much, you could use `find` instead without creating a collection beforehand

```js
const array = [
   { home1: "05:45", dayOfWeek: 1, away: "09:30"},
   { home1: "05:15", dayOfWeek: 2, away: "09:30"},
   { home1: "17:30", dayOfWeek: 5, away: "09:30"},
   { home1: "16:30", dayOfWeek: 7, away: "09:30"}
];
const dummy = { home1: "05:30", away: "09:30" };
for (let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
  if (!array.find(({ dayOfWeek }) => dayOfWeek === i)) {
    array.push({ ...dummy, dayOfWeek: i });
  }
}
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Array.from" and loop 7 times like below.

```js
const array = [
   { home1: "05:45", dayOfWeek: 1, away: "09:30"},
   { home1: "05:15", dayOfWeek: 2, away: "09:30"},
   { home1: "17:30", dayOfWeek: 5, away: "09:30"},
   { home1: "16:30", dayOfWeek: 7, away: "09:30"}
]

// sort array by day of week. Ignore this step if you are sure it will be sorted always
array.sort((a,b) => a.dayOfWeek - b.dayOfWeek)

var result = Array.from({ length: 7}
    , (_,i) => array[0].dayOfWeek == i + 1
                ? array.shift()
                : { home1: "05:30", dayOfWeek: i + 1, away: "09:30"})
                
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **Array.reduce** to create a set of existing days. Now iterate and check whether there is an entry in set, if not push the object in array.

```js
const array = [
   { home1: "05:45", dayOfWeek: 1, away: "09:30"},
   { home1: "05:15", dayOfWeek: 2, away: "09:30"},
   { home1: "17:30", dayOfWeek: 5, away: "09:30"},
   { home1: "16:30", dayOfWeek: 7, away: "09:30"}
];
let daysSet = array.reduce((a,c) => a.add(c.dayOfWeek), new Set());
let obj = { home1: "16:30", dayOfWeek: 7, away: "09:30"};
for(let i = 1; i <=7; i++) {
  if(!daysSet.has(i)) array.push(Object.assign({}, obj, {dayOfWeek:i}));
}
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't test it but I made an upvote because the first answer is worked for me

Comment: Could you please upvote my question. Else I will be blocked by asking

Answer (score 1):

You can first get all the *dayOfWeek* present in a array with `map()`. Then use *for* loop to insert the *dayOfWeek* by checking whether that is present in the array or not.

You can try the following way:

```js
const array = [
   { home1: "05:45", dayOfWeek: 1, away: "09:30"},
   { home1: "05:15", dayOfWeek: 2, away: "09:30"},
   { home1: "17:30", dayOfWeek: 5, away: "09:30"},
   { home1: "16:30", dayOfWeek: 7, away: "09:30"}
]
let exist = array.map(d => d.dayOfWeek);

for(let i = 1; i<=7; i++){
  let dummy = { home1: "05:30", dayOfWeek: 7, away: "09:30"};
  dummy.dayOfWeek = i;
  if(!exist.includes(i))
   array.splice(i-1, 0, dummy);
}
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Could you please upvote my question. Else I will be blocked by asking